# MySQL with Japanese characters

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying to figure out how to create a table such that I can insert Japanese names into it. Right now I have:

```
Type: InnoDB
Encoding: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Collation: utf8_general_ci
```

However, when I insert the characters, it shows up as `????`. And when I retrieve the data using `SELECT`, it also shows up as `????`. What do I need to do such that I can properly store and retrieve Japanese characters (kanji, hiragana, and katakana)?

Comment: What is the `default charset` of the table which you are planning on storing these chars?

Comment: @MikePurcell Where can I find that information? Is this it:   `CHARACTER SET latin1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing an `ALTER` to `charset` `utf8` solved the issue:

```
ALTER TABLE title MODIFY 
    column VARCHAR (100)
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Nice, looks like you fixed it. Also you may want to be sure your connections are set to utf-8 by default. More info @ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect

Comment: @MikePurcell that would be: `SET GLOBAL init_connect='SET character_set=utf-8';` ?

Comment: In my MySQL config file (/etc/my.cnf) under the server section (mysqld), I have `init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8'`. Which ensures any connections to your database will also support utf8 chars.