# View Japanese Characters in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, mysql-workbench

I already tried [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352404/mysql-with-japanese-characters) which says

```
ALTER TABLE title 
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Ok here are some screen shots which might help you.
[image: problem showing image]

**Update**
here's what happens when i insert Japanese characters.
[image: Insert query]

**Update 2**
Show create table gives this

```
CREATE TABLE `productInfo` (
  `pID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pOperation` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `season` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `pName` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `margin1` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `margin2` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

just see that 
**`DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci`**

But now see that the query

```
SELECT character_set_name, collation_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'trac_data'
    AND table_name = 'productInfo'
    AND column_name = 'pOperation';
```

gives

**`character_set_name  collation_name`**

```
'latin1'            'latin1_swedish_ci'
```

Thats weird !

**Update 3**

```
SELECT hex(pOperation),pOperation FROM trac_data.productInfo;
```

gave 3F3F3F3F3F  which is hex code for actual '?' and not any japanese character so that means no japanese characters are being stored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mix of charsets in your table structure. The table itself uses utf8, but the column in question uses latin 1. You have it defined that way. As long as you have an own charset for your column you can change the table's or the schema's column a thousand times. It won't have any effect on your column. So, instead change the column's charset to either default (to use that of the table) or make it using utf8 explicitely.

When you alter the column's charset existing data will be converted (if possible). Your wrong input however stays wrong, so you have to fill the data again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the cause

```
CREATE TABLE `productInfo` (
  `pID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pOperation` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `season` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `pName` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `margin1` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `margin2` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I noticed how in front of each column  **`SET latin1`** was present.

So I Just changed to **`sjis`** and problem solved.

Comment: That's what I wrote in my answer. I don't see any use of this additional answer. Also, the charset info is not in front but (nearly) at the end of your column definition (only followed by the default value) and secondly, you have defined your table to use utf8. You should not make single columns then using a less flexible charset. Instead, remove the charset clause altogether, to make the column use the table's charset (here utf8).

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the database collation to `UTF-8`, not only the table collation :

[image]

Here is the SQL script result :

[image]

Comment: see the first image, i think you missed it

Comment: -1: The schema charset is totally unrelated unless you have set your table charset to use the schema default. As soon as you set a table charset or even an individual column charset the schema charset is irrelevant. Additionally, your screenshot is from modeling, not the SQL IDE:

Comment: If you set the database to use a UTF-8 collation,  tables/columns will be in UTF-8 (as it will use the default collation of the schema). I think it is a good thing to set a UTF-8 collation by default. Well it is my personal experience, maybe I'm wrong. ;)

Comment: I don't think the OP uses the SQL IDE, he uses the insert tab of the modeling (which I manage to crash sometimes just by clicking twice on the Apply buttons... I don't know why?). But maybe I haven't understood what you call the SQL IDE ? ;)